# Length extension attack in the middle help!

Tags: hash, md5, password-hashing

is it possible to insert the command that you want to execute in the middle of the md5 hash token already known?

Comment: Explain what you mean.

Comment: Length extension attacks are particular to keyed hash functions. However, you've not described how the "MD5 hash token" is generated and thus if length extension attacks are feasible or if they even apply.